# How to Fix text of UILabel word Character cut on Bottom side

Tags: uilabel, nsattributedstring, uifont

my following Code is

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *body1stParagraph = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];

      body1stParagraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        body1stParagraph.minimumLineHeight  = _font_Size;
        attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:font_name size:Font_size],
                   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : body1stParagraph,
                   NSAttachmentAttributeName: textAttachment};
```

and this Dictionary add on Attributed String

```
[attributeString addAttributes:attrs range:lineRange];
```

but text of label is Cut

[image]

Comment: Have you used constraint for your label?

Comment: No, i label Add programmatically @vishal

Comment: Then change the frame of your label. Height of your label is not enough to accommodate the multiline text.

Answer (score -1):

this may solve your problem -

```
yourLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: i already give label sizeToFit  but does not work label @Anupam